# Sending consecutive sms messages with Twilio the second message arrives before the first

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-node

I have an issue when trying to send 2 consecutive messages via nodejs teilio

My `sendMessage` function looks like this

```
client.messages.create({
        body: msg,
        to: toNumber,
        from: keys.TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER,
    })
    .then(async (message) => {
        res.send("Ok, good job");
    });
```

And I am using it like this

```
sendChatMessage(
    "Message body to send",
    req.body.From,
    res
);
```

And then

```
sendChatMessage(
    "Follow up message body to send",
    req.body.From,
    res
);
```

However the follow up message arrives before the first message I tried putting the 2nd message in a timeout for a few seconds but it doesn't feel like the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing us enough of your code but it looks like you may not actually waiting for your async calls to succeed before sending the second call?  You need to make sure you are awaiting async calls and or returning promises and participating in the promise chains.